# Intellij IDEA doesn't show up available suggestions for android resources in Kotlin files

Tags: android, intellij-idea, r.java-file, kotlin

I have a Kotlin file where I want access some Android resources through R.java file. In this case Intellij IDEA doesn't show up available suggestions kinda like `R.layout.main`

Please look at this screenshot [image: No suggestion for Android resources in Kotlin files]

Is it an issue in IDEA/Kotlin plugin or I have to configure something?

```
Kotlin plugin 0.7.270.1
Intellij IDEA IC-135.1019
Andorid API 19
Java 7
Android Build tools 19.1
```

Comment: Did you ever file a bug in the Kotlin YouTrack as suggsted by @andrey?  If so, what is the issue number (or better, the link) and was it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Kotlin plugin. Please report bugs to our issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but, I would recommend following the docs for android http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

I can see, for example, in your screenshot you don't have separate folders for kotlin and java with /src/main/java /src/main/kotlin

Maybe seeing your gradle file could be of some help.

Right now I'm using kotlin 0.10.195 with android 1.1, build tools 21.1.2 and gradle plugin 1.0.1 , and suggestions are working fine.